# Is deconvolution commutative?

Tags: convolution

Convolution is commutative:

> $f \star g  = g \star f$

where $f$ and $g$ are functions, and $\star$ the convolution operator.

Does deconvolution possess this commutative property?

Comment: Multiplication of numbers is commutative.  Division is the analog of deconvolution.  Is division commutative?

Comment: No need for sarcasm.

Comment: That's not sarcasm.  Deconvolution is equivalent to division by the fourier transforms, so your knowledge of division will immediately answer your question without any further explanation.